# std::vector и спрайты SFML

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

Суть проблемы такова: создаю вектор для объектов, который нужно будет расширять со временем.

```
vector<Object> obj
{
Object("obj/mel.png", 500, 200),
}
```

Ну и вывожу его в цикле окна. Но спрайта на экране я не получаю. Можете подсказать, что не так?

Класс Object:

```
    class Object {
public:
    int w, h, x, y;
    String File;
    Image image;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    
    Object(String F, float X, float Y) {
        File = F;
        
        image.loadFromFile("" + File);
        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        x = X; y = Y;
        this->File = F;
        this->x = X;
        this->y = Y;
        sprite.setPosition(x, y);
        //sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, w, h));
    }
    
};
```

Ну и в конце цикла while(window.isOpen()) вывожу спрайт:

```
window.draw(obj[0].sprite);
```

Comment: Так покажите как выводите. Этого кода мало.

Comment: @EOF window.draw(obj[0].sprite);

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: loadFromFile возвращает bool. если не получилось - будет false. Проверьте. Может просто не находит файл

Answer (score 0):

Вы храните текстуры в объектах типа `Object`. Объекты `sf::Sprite` хранят указатели на текстуры. Соответственно, при копировании объекта, текстура и спрайт будут скопированы и получится, что указатель в спрайте указывает на текстуру в предыдущем объекте.

```
vector<Object> obj
{
    Object("obj/mel.png", 500, 200),
}
```

Создаете временный объект, который копируется в вектор, а затем удаляется, и указатель в спрайте указывает на удаленную текстуру.

И тоже самое будет при реаллокации вектором памяти. Текстуры и спрайты перененутся в другую область памяти, но указатели в спрайтах будут указывать на удаленные текстуры.

Comment: а разве конструктор копирования у Object не скопирует корректно? Странно было бы, если Texture  или Sprite не могли себя копировать корректно.

Comment: @KoVadim нет. Текстура не знает о том, что на нее указатель из спрайта указывает. А спрайт просто скопирует указатель и всё.

Comment: @KoVadim я не думаю, что ТС реализовал глубокое копирование для своего класса. Собственно,  текстуры никто не хранит прямо в используемом объекте.

Comment: я разобрался. Ваш ответ хоть и правильный, но очень плохо сформулирован. К сожалению, класс текстур написан очень я бы сказал плохо. ключевая цитата "The texture argument refers to a texture that must exist as long as the sprite uses it."

Comment: @KoVadim по-моему, реализован как обычно. Текстура - это именно сам ресурс, а спрайт - view.